# Python turning a tuple into a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have searched but I can't find anything that works... I was hoping that someone might be able to help me out.

I am trying to get a tuple and change it into an ordered dict:

```
mylist = [(5, 3), (1, 4), (1, 7), (12, 7), (8, 3), (12, 4), (12, 5)]
```

And change it into:

```
myorderedlist = [(1, 7), (1, 4), (5, 3), (8, 3), (12, 7), (12, 5), (12, 4)]
```

And then (I need it to get rid of the smaller values as well):

```
mydic = {1:7, 5:3, 8:3, 12:7}
```

In total I am trying to get `mylist = [(5, 3), (1, 4), (1, 7), (12, 7), (8, 3), (12, 4), (12, 5)]` into `mydic = {1:7, 5:3, 8:3, 12:7}`

Ps. If you think you know something that could help me, please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the list first. This will rearrange the list based on `(x, y)` values of each item. Items with the same `x` value will be sorted by their `y` values.

Then you can convert it into an `OrderedDict` and keep the sorted order with no pain.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

mylist = [(5, 3), (1, 4), (1, 7), (12, 7), (8, 3), (12, 4), (12, 5)]
mylist.sort()
print mylist

mydict = OrderedDict()
mydict.update(mylist)
print mydict
```

The output:

```
[(1, 4), (1, 7), (5, 3), (8, 3), (12, 4), (12, 5), (12, 7)]
OrderedDict([(1, 7), (5, 3), (8, 3), (12, 7)])
```

Comment: What does `print dd` do? @Rikka

Comment: Sorry, it should be print mydict

Answer (score 0):

This also works.

```
In [1]: a = [(5, 3), (1, 4), (1, 7), (12, 7), (8, 3), (12, 4), (12, 5)]

In [2]: dict(sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])))
Out[2]: {1: 7, 5: 3, 8: 3, 12: 7}
```

Comment: The `lambda` key is unnecessary. The default sorting method does exactly the same thing.

Comment: What does `key=lambda` actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
>>> mylist = [(5, 3), (1, 4), (1, 7), (12, 7), (8, 3), (12, 4), (12, 5)]
>>> smaller = 2 # for example
>>> mydic = {k:v for k,v in mylist if v > smaller}
>>> mydic
{8: 3, 1: 7, 12: 5, 5: 3}
>>>
```

notice that if a key is repeated in the tuple, the previous one will be replaced.